# How to store flask sessions on serverless APP

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, auth0, serverless-framework

I'm trying to build a serverless Flask APP. To login users, I use auth0.com.

After the user logs in I get an access token, I send a post request with it to my flask backend and there I exchange the token for the user info doing this:

```
@app.route('/callback', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def callback_handling():
    resp = request.get_json()
    url = 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/userinfo'
    headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer ' + resp['access_token']}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    userinfo = r.json()

    # Store the tue user information in flask session.
    session['jwt_payload'] = userinfo
    session['profile'] = {
                            'user_id': userinfo['sub'],
                            'name': userinfo['name'],
                            'picture': userinfo['picture']
                        }
```

Once I've done this I redirect the user to their dashboard. There I send a second post request to fetch the user profile, something like this:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def user_profile():
    if 'profile' in session:
        return jsonify({'profile':session['profile']})
    else:
         return jsonify({'profile':"Not logged in"})
```

This second function returns always `{'profile':"Not logged in"}`.

So I'm wondering what's the best way to do this. Should I always send back the `auth0` token, send a request to them to ask who is the user and then return his data? It seems like an overkill to send always a request to auth0 everytime I need to return some data. Is there a better method?

Comment: Your overall strategy for a traditional web app is definitely correct: once you obtain an access_token from the authorization server (Auth0), you make a request to the `/userinfo` endpoint to find information about the user, and create a server-side session (most likely cookie-based) to store that information. Interaction with the authorization server ends at that point.

Comment: What seems to be failing here is the session storage/retrieval, so you might want to reframe your question to troubleshoot that part.
I assumed you looked into https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/python/01-login for a working sample.

Comment: Hi @NicoSabena yes, I did look at that, however that's for a simple "classic" flask app and they use the storage as I do. I really don't know what I'm missing here..

Comment: Leaving authentication concerns aside for a moment, can you successfully create a session for a user, store some data and retrieve it on a later request?

Comment: Hi @NicoSabena, I made some tests, I proxied all the calls through [webpack dev server proxies](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) and it seems to work now. Is this enough as a login system? Won't I need anything else? Won't sessions mix between users? Thanks!

Comment: Your application mostly interacts with Auth0 (or any other OIDC-based auth system) at login time, to identify who the user is, and then you create a session cookie that identifies the user within your app. So as long as the cookie and the session are properly kept (usually taken care by frameworks) you should be OK.